# Change index of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I want to center clicked list element (so, for example, If I click the very left one then it moves to the middle, replacing the current middle element).

So I thought that maybe switching the indexes of current "active" and clicked element might be worth a shot. I couldn't change the index value of element though.

The best solution is to change index of every list element so they will keep some logical order and center the clicked one.

I am beginner in JS so I am aware that there is probably better way of doing it so I'm open for suggestions. ;)

**So, two solutions I was thinking about:**

It replaces its place with the clicked element. For example:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 
3 is middle and I click 5 
The new order : 1 - 2 - 5 - 4 - 3
```

It moves every element of the list. For example:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 
3 is middle and I click 5 
The new order : 3 - 4 - 5 - 1 - 2
```

Here is codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMOZVd

```js
function horizontalSlider() {
  var sliderElement = $('.horizontal-slider ul li');
  var active = $('.horizontal-slider .active');
  var activeIndex = active.index();
  var center = Math.floor(sliderElement.length / 4);

  sliderElement.click(function() {
    var thisElement = $(this).index();
    var newActive = $('.horizontal-slider .active');
    var newActiveIndex = newActive.index();
    if (thisElement == newActiveIndex) {
      $(this).addClass('active').children().addClass('active-sub');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active').children().addClass('active-sub');
      newActive.removeClass('active').children().removeClass('active-sub');
    }
  });
}

horizontalSlider();
```

```css
.horizontal-slider {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.horizontal-slider ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.horizontal-slider ul li {
  padding: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.horizontal-slider ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  transition: all .5s ease;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
.active-sub {
  top: 70%;
  left: 1%;
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
}
.active-sub li {
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="horizontal-slider relative">
  <ul>
    <li>Mar 16
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Apr 04
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>May 22
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="active">Jun 30
      <ul class="active-sub">
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Jul 12
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Aug 15
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Sep 03
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: by `center the clicked on` do you mean that it should be in the middle ? what about klicking the very left, should this then be in the middle an no other el on the left ?, pls clarify

Comment: @johnSmith - yes, it should be in the middle.

If I click the very left one then it moves to the middle, replacing the current middle element.

Comment: What about the middle? Where is he "going"?

Comment: @MoshFeu so there are two solutions I was thinking about. 

1. It replaces its place with the clicked element. For example: 

1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 
3 is middle and I click 5

The new order : 1 - 2 - 5 - 4 - 3

2. It moves every element of the list. For example: 

1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 
3 is middle and I click 5

The new order : 3 - 4 - 5 - 1 - 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to remove the node and insert it to other place, you need to use `animation` instead of `transition`.

Let me know if something is not clear.

```js
function horizontalSlider() {
  var sliderElement = $('.horizontal-slider ul li');
  var active = $('.horizontal-slider .active');
  var activeIndex = active.index();
  var center = Math.floor(sliderElement.length / 4);

  sliderElement.click(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var thisElement = elem.index();
    var newActive = $('.horizontal-slider .active');
    var newActiveIndex = newActive.index();
    if (thisElement == newActiveIndex) {
      elem.addClass('active').children().addClass('active-sub');
    } else {
      elem.addClass('active').children().addClass('active-sub');
      console.log(thisElement < 3);
      var middle = $('.horizontal-slider>ul>li:nth-child(' + (thisElement < 3 ? '4' : '3') + ')');
      $(this).insertAfter(middle);
      newActive.removeClass('active').children().removeClass('active-sub');
    }
  });
}

horizontalSlider();
```

```css
.horizontal-slider {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.horizontal-slider ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.horizontal-slider ul li {
  padding: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.horizontal-slider ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  animation: active .5s ease forwards;
}
.active-sub {
  top: 70%;
  left: 1%;
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
}
.active-sub li {
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes active {
  to {
    font-weight: 900;
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(1.25);  
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="horizontal-slider relative">
  <ul>
    <li>Mar 16
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Apr 04
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>May 22
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="active">Jun 30
      <ul class="active-sub">
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Jul 12
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Aug 15
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Sep 03
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ips</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So i changed some things and added a div to each text element so you can edit it individually

Now Everything will come in the center.

See the Pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGrBRJ

code`    function horizontalSlider() {

```
  var sliderElement = $('.horizontal-slider ul li');



  sliderElement.click(function() {

    var active = $('.horizontal-slider .active .t1');
    var t1 = active.text();
    var t3 = $('.horizontal-slider .active').find(".t3").text();
    var thisElement = $(this);
    var t2 = thisElement.children(".t2").text();
    var t4 = thisElement.find(".t4").text();

    thisElement.children(".t2").text(t1);
    thisElement.find(".t4").text(t3);

    active.text(t2);
    $('.horizontal-slider .active .t3').text(t4);
  });
}

horizontalSlider();`
```

Answer (score 0):

What You can do is instead of switching the styles,you can switch the text in Them.
It can be easily done by getting the by using:

```
    (".whateverElement").html();
```

Then Swap it

Comment: This would be a good solution BUT not in this case I think.

Using .html() or .text() deletes the nested list inside the parent LI element.

Thank you though!